# Need help with differentiating a problem

Tags: calculus, differential

I am attempting to differentiate: 
$$f(x)= \dfrac{x^{0.5}}{2x^{1.5}}$$

i first simplified the fraction by subracting the exponemts leaving me with:
$\frac{x}{2x}$

Then I simplified the fraction further giving me:
$\frac{1}{x}$

using law of exponents i rearanged the fraction to:
$x^{-1}$

Finally using the power rule, i differentiated to obtain:
$-x^{-2}$

I got this wrong and i dont know where i went wrong with it, can someone help me point out my errors?

Thank you

Comment: The exponents are simplified incorrectly...should be $\dfrac{1}{2x}$

Comment: How did you convert $\frac x{2x}$ into $\frac1x$?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $x^{-1}$ is $-x^{-2}$ as you correctly pointed out. Now the function can be simplified to $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{-1}$$
So you just need to multiply the derivative of $x^{-1}$ by $1/2$:
$$f'(x) =-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}$$

ALSO, just to clarify how you should go about simplifying the exponents step by step:
$$f(x)=\dfrac{x^{0.5}}{2x^{1.5}}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2x^{1.5}x^{-0.5}}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2x^{1.5-0.5}}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2x^{1}}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2x}$$

Comment: where did the 1/2 come from?

Comment: updated the answer accordingly. Should be clarified

Comment: ah i see now. Thanks bud

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x)= \dfrac{x^{0.5}}{2x^{1.5}}=\frac12x^{0.5-1.5}=\frac12x^{-1}$$ so $$f'(x)=\frac12(-1)x^{-2}=-\frac1{2x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

it simplifies to $$\frac{1}{2x}$$ and the first derivative is given by $$\frac{1}{2}(-1)x^{-2}$$

Comment: How did you get to 1/2x? To my understanding we have      x/x•x, so we then cancel out an x from the top and bottom

Comment: by the power rule is $$\frac{x^{1/2}}{2x^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{2x^{3/2-1/2}}$$

Comment: @ShashuadaMathematician: $2\cdot x \neq x \cdot x$